# ImportError _tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "/home/pi/sudoku.py", line 3, in <module>
>   from _tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, Button, BOTH, TOP, BOTTOM
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Tk'
> ```

I am trying to program a GUI based sudoku game with tkinter. The tutorial I found is in python2, and i've been working to translate it to python 3. The error I keep getting is that Tk, tk, cannot be imported.

Does anyone know why?

***I am NEW to coding and programming and yes i've googled it.***

Comment: Please create a [mcve] so we can see how you're importing tkinter.

Comment: Are you familar with [tkinterbook](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-whats-tkinter.htm)

Comment: How about a wrapper for tkinter?  Take a look at PySimpleGUI. It wraps tkinter so you don't have to directly deal with it. You'll be able to understand it very quickly without so much struggle.

Answer (score 1):

From the python documentation: "The Tk interface is located in a binary module named _tkinter. This module contains the low-level interface to Tk, and should never be used directly by application programmers."
https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, Button, BOTH, TOP, BOTTOM
```

Answer (score -1):

In the import statement it is enough to just say:

```
import _tkinter as Tk
```

This imports everything including Canvas, Frame and Button classes. If you do want to import specific classes you need to specify it with a . like this:

```
import _tkinter.Canvas as TkCanvas
```

the alias (Tk or TkCanvas) you can choose yourself. Just pick something short and recognisable, also picking the same one as the tutorial makes the tutorial easyer to follow.

Good luck!

Comment: No, you should never directly import `_tkinter`.